# What axis should my two variables be on?

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm producing a report based on the speed of a program i've written however I'm not sure which axis time and the number I enter in the program should go on.

My scenario: I've written a program and to test the speed i've entered different numbers (10,000 20,000 30,000) etc and i've recorded the time taken. Which axis does the numbers i've entered go on? and which axis does time go on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure which axis time and the number I enter in the program
>   should go on.

While the choice is entirely up to you, a typical format would be to put the number you enter on the horizontal ('x') axis, and the result (speed of program) would go on the vertical ('y') axis.

This is because you can think of the speed of the program as the result of which button you enter.

If you were talking about an event dependent on time

Such as: Event A happens **at** Noon, Event B happens **at** 1 PM
Versus: Event A happens **in** 2 mins, Event B happens **in** 3 mins

Then you would be better off using time on the X-Axis.

Answer (score 0):

The independent variable (on the x-axis) is the one that you decide ahead of time.  It is the one that has is known before you start the experiment.  In this case, you chose to enter different numbers (10,000 etc.).  The dependent variable, on the y-axis, is the measured results.  In this case, it is the time your program takes.